# Android Application Crashing Unexpectedly

Tags: android

I am having a problem where my application is unexpectdly stopping. This is meant to be a simply application that let's the user enter in the number of dice and a filter number. It is crashing unexpectedly, even though I cleaned it multiple times. 
Here is the java file:

```
package com.greg.rostov.dice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class DiceRoller extends Activity {
DiceRoller r=new DiceRoller();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button roll=(Button)findViewById(R.id.roll);

    roll.setOnClickListener(onRoll);
}
private View.OnClickListener onRoll=new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            EditText numberofdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll);
            EditText filterdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll);
        }
    };




private String numberofdice="";
private String filterdice="";

public String getNumberofdice() {
    return(numberofdice);
}
public void setNumberofdice(String numberofdice){
    this.numberofdice=numberofdice;
}

public String getFilterdice() {
    return(filterdice);
}
public void setFilterdice(String filterdice){
    this.filterdice=filterdice;
}
}
```

And here is the error log:

```
    09-10 09:41:09.937: D/AndroidRuntime(551): Shutting down VM
    09-10 09:41:09.937: W/dalvikvm(551): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x40015560)
    09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.greg.rostov.dice/com.greg.rostov.dice.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TableLayout
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.widget.TableLayout
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:386)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at com.greg.rostov.dice.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 11 more
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 21 more
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #000000 from drawable resource ID #0x7f050004
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1714)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1951)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1899)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:286)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:120)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.widget.TableLayout.<init>(TableLayout.java:105)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 24 more
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: #000000
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:406)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1706)
09-10 09:41:09.977: E/AndroidRuntime(551):  ... 30 more
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@string/backgroundcolor"
android:stretchColumns="1" 
>
<TableRow>
    <TextView 
     android:text="Dice:"
     android:textColor="@string/textcolor"
     android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/dicebox"
        android:inputType="text" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow>
    <TextView 
    android:text="Filter"
    android:textColor="@string/textcolor"
    android:textSize="16dp"/>
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/filterdicebox"/>
</TableRow>
<Button android:id="@+id/roll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/textonbutton"
    android:textSize="25dp"
    />
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Your application is trying to find a drawable named `#000000`. Which is the color black, not a drawable. I feel like you've put this somewhere in your XML that it doesn't belong.

Comment: the logcat tells you it's an error in your layout XML file,  at line #2. please post that file so we could help.

Comment: Yes. It is the background color of my xml.

Comment: Please click the "edit" link in your question, and edit your question to include your layout file that is causing the crash.

Comment: Edited the code block of the log to include my xml. The code function is such a pain. Scroll down to see it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is in your XML file, here:

```
android:background="@string/backgroundcolor"
```

What you're doing here is passing in a string to a field which should take a color or drawable reference. As far as I know it doesn't matter if the string in question is a valid color string (like #012). This won't be treated like a preprocessor macro where the text is substituted in, rather it will look it up at runtime and get a value it doesn't expect.

To fix it, change the definition from

```
<string name="backgroundcolor">#000000</string>
```

to

```
<color name="backgroundcolor">#000000</color>
```

and refer to it in your layout file as

```
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the solution. However, I used <color name="backgroundcolor">#000000</color> instead of string and it worked.

Comment: Oops I actually mixed up what I said, meant to say change from string to color, not vice versa (will edit now) :P  Glad I could help though :)

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully, someone else will see it and get their program fixed :D

Answer (score 0):

Look at your listener:

```
private View.OnClickListener onRoll=new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        EditText numberofdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll);
        EditText filterdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.roll);
    }
};
```

Your refer to the same id for both EditText: numberofdice and filterdice.

Change it to:

```
private View.OnClickListener onRoll=new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v){
    EditText numberofdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dicebox);
    EditText filterdice=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.filterdicebox);
}
```

};